# Trouble with calling a PHP function in Javascript via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax to implement a php function in my html file (that contains javascript). I am trying to get all files locally that are JSON files. I tried my best to follow this: http://tinyurl.com/n7zttd9 but I am having trouble. For some reason, I am getting undefined in my alert statement (which is the closest thing I could get to a print statement so far, but if there are other options to print, I am very open to them). Here is some of my code for my local html file:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code

function AjaxCaller(){
    var xmlhttp;
    try{
        // for firefox, safari, opera
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch(e){
        try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e){
            try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch(E){
                xmlhttp = false;
                alert("Your browser broke!");
            }
        }
    }

    if(!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined'){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function callPage(url, div){
    ajax=AjaxCaller();
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);

    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(ajax.readyState==4){
            if(ajax.status==0){
                div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send(null);

}
//-->
</script>

<script id='code-js' type="text/javascript">
/*...*/
function load(){


    var jsonstuff = callPage('findjson.php', document.getElementById('checkjson'));
    alert(jsonstuff);

    Scene.loadObject(jsonstuff);

}
/*...*/
</script>
```

Here is my php code (file is findjson.php locally)

```
<?php
function checkjson() {
    foreach (glob("*.json") as $filename) {
        return $filename;
    }
?>
```

I used an ajax.status code of 0 because I found online that it has to be 0 for locally. I put alert statement at almost every line, and it seemed to pass through all code ok (like it had an status of 0 and a readyState of 4). I think my Id for document.getElementById is wrong, but I'm not sure what else to put. I know in the url I posted that they used targetId, but I don't think I should use it since I don't define it.

Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you so much :)

Comment: it must be `echo` instead of `return`

Comment: As per 6 zillion other dupes on this site: AJAX is asynchronous. The xmlhttp stuff will execute, then immediately return and allow your alert to execute. At some LATER point, the response from the server comes in, by which time your code has moved on and is off doing other things.

Comment: Your PHP code should also be syntactically correct. And an AJAX call does not invoke PHP functions by itself, it can only request pages. -- But as said already, you should utilize well-written AJAX utility code first (jQuery), instead of copy&pasting something as cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code needs to `echo` the data not `return` it. Because the function is being called by AJAX, not another PHP function, the call needs to be treated from a PHP standpoint as a page request, not a function call. Make sure something is also calling the function when AJAX invokes that php script.

```
<?php
function checkjson() {
    foreach (glob("*.json") as $filename) {
        echo $filename;
    }
checkjson();
?>
```

Your second problem is that `Scene.loadObject(jsonstuff);` will have already executed before the ajax can alter the page with the response. That function needs to be called after the ajax request completes inside of the following block: (Also the status code for success is 200, not 0.)

```
if(ajax.status == 200){
   div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
}
```

Edit: Using jQUery will also make your life much easier.

Comment: @Musa That's the response handler block from the code OP posted.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, missed that completely.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous. The request won't have completed when your `alert` shows you `undefined`. You need to use a callback function to wait until your request has completed, before you'll be able to access the server's response.